# Column of a csv file is returning undefined when reading values in d3 from a csv file

Tags: d3.js

I am reading values from a csv file into d3.js and it is returning undifined only for a column in the csv file and all the other columns are returning values:

My csv first row:
Gender,Age,Program
Female,24,New Time (Underg.)

Here Program is returning undefined values

My d3.js code:

```
   function csvToJSONFirstTimeAdmissionBySchool(csv){
         var x = [];
         d3.csv(csv, function(d) {
         return {
             Gender : d.Gender,
             Age : d.Age,
             Program : d["Program"],
             };
         }, function(data) {
         console.log(data[1]);
       });
    }
```

My output:

{Gender: "Male", Age : 24 , Program: undefined}

Comment: What version of d3js are you using?

Comment: should it be d["Program Female"]?